# css doesn't work properly on mobile device in react native

Tags: android, css, reactjs, react-native, android-studio

I'm trying to center an error message in my app, but it looks different in Android Studio than Chrome.

[image]

[image]

As you can see in the images, the error message and the icon are not aligned for Android Studio device (I'm emulating Pixel 2 in both places)

I'm using StyleSheet from react-native and the css is:

```
errorMessage: {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
}
```

Is there any way to use the F12 tools or something similar for Android Studio?

Comment: try marginTop: 'auto', marginBottom: 'auto' on text

Answer (score 1):

In React Native, Flex works a bit differently than in CSS. For example, every view is flex by default and with `alignItems: 'center'` and `justifyContent: 'center'` you can center the `items.Display` Flex is not necessary in React Native and I don't think it is supported.

So for the `errorMessage` would I rather use these styles:

```
errorMessageContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
}
```

Furthermore, you can call the dev menu as follows and start the "Show Inspector":

```
adb shell input keyevent 82
```